# Solve for $x$ in the following trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sqrt 2\cos^2 x-\cos x=0$$
Solve for $x$ algebraically, where $x$ is greater than or equal to zero, and less than $2\pi$. Answer must be an exact solution.

To be honest, I don't know where to start with this one. I know I need to isolate $\cos x$, but I have little idea as to what I need to do to get there. Is subtracting $\cos x$ from both sides the best way to go about this?

---

Here is one thing I tried.

[image]

Am I completely on the wrong track here?

---

EDIT:

$\sqrt{2}\cos x - 1 = 0$

$\cos x = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = 45^\circ$

$360 - 45 = 315^\circ = \dfrac{7\pi}{4}$

$\cos x = 0$
$x = 0$ at $90^\circ$, or $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $270^\circ$ or $\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$

So:

**$x = \dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{4}, \dfrac{3\pi}{2}, \dfrac{7\pi}{4}$**

Comment: $\frac{cos(x)}{cos^2(x)}=\frac{cos(x)}{cos(x)\times cos(x)}=\frac{1}{cos(x)}$

Comment: Your first step should be to factor the left hand side so you can solve for both solutions.  Like you would for $4x^2-x=0$ to $x(4x-1)=0$

Comment: Do not divide by $\cos x$ because you may be eliminating a solution if $\cos x = 0$.  Instead, you should factor, then use the Zero Product Rule (if a product is equal to zero, then one of its factors must equal zero).

Comment: Your revised solutions are correct.

Comment: You are welcome.  If you click on edit, you can see the LaTeX syntax I used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Factor out a $\cos(x)$ from your original expression to get:

$$0 = \sqrt{2} \cos^2(x) - \cos(x) = \cos(x)(\sqrt{2}\cos(x)-1)$$

From here, you know $\cos(x)=0$ or $\sqrt{2}\cos(x)-1 = 0$. Do you see where to go from here?

Comment: Yes, I think so. See edit.. Did I solve correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your help :) Noted.

Comment: Your final answers are correct, well done :) However, I have a few comments to make on your procedure. In your edit you state that $\cos(x) = -1/ \sqrt{2}$, when in fact you should have $\cos(x) = 1/ \sqrt{2}$. In the third line of your edit you say $1/\sqrt{2} = 45^\circ$. I believe you mean to say that $\cos(x) = 1/\sqrt{2}$ when $x = 45^\circ = \pi/4 \text{rads}$.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

We have: $\sqrt{2}\cos^{2}(x)-\cos(x)=0$

Let's factor out a $\cos(x)$ to get:

$\Rightarrow \cos(x)\big(\sqrt{2}\cos(x)-1\big)=0$

As we have a product that equals to zero, either one of the multiples must equal to zero:

$\Rightarrow \cos(x)=0 \Rightarrow x=\arccos(0)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, $\hspace{1 mm}\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$

$\Rightarrow \sqrt{2}\cos(x)-1=0 \Rightarrow x=\arccos\bigg(\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\bigg)=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$, $\hspace{1 mm}\dfrac{7\pi}{4}$

Therefore, the solutions to the equation are $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, $x=\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$, $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ and $x=\dfrac{7\pi}{4}$.